# How to sort / filter / search data and display in modal in Laravel Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Scenario 1

I am using v-for loop to print categories on button, now when I click on button it should show me the data related to that category. It is working fine when i use dropdown select category and click search and it displays all the related data.

But how to do it on button click event.

===== 
Fetching categories in Button using v-for directives

```
<form @submit.prevent="product_info_form">
                <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-3 px-2" v-for="(category, index) in categories" v-bind:value="category.slack" v-bind:key="index">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block py-4 margin-bottom" v-on:click="displaynumbers" v-bind:value="category.slack">{{ category.label }}</button>
                    </div>
                    <select name="category" v-model="category" class="form-control custom-select custom-select-lg">
                        <option value="">Filter by Category..</option>
                        <option v-for="(category, index) in categories" v-bind:value="category.slack" v-bind:key="index">
                        {{ category.label }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
```

In method I have written following code :

displaynumbers: function(e)
            {

```
            var buttonValue = e.target.value;
            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append("access_token", window.settings.access_token);
            //formData.append("barcode", this.barcode);
            //formData.append("product_title", this.product_title);

            if(buttonValue != '')
            {
                alert(buttonValue);
                formData.append("product_category", this.buttonValue);        
            }   
            else
            {
                alert('Null vlaue passed');
            }

            axios.post('/api/get_product', formData).then((response) => {
                this.product_processing = false;
                console.log(response.data.data);

                 this.product_list = response.data.data;
                 if(this.barcode !='' && this.product_list.length == 1){
                     this.add_to_cart(this.product_list[0]);
                     this.barcode = '';
                 }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        },
```

Comment: a code sample would be handy

Comment: Provide more information with examples

Comment: I have updated the post, could you please help me if you can.